# Custom form and field calculation QGIS

Tags: qgis, qt

I wonder if it is possible using a custom form  for field calculation to be carried out by means of a calculate button.

I have 4 input fields, I enter in two fields manualy a number, after pressing the button the rest of the fields are calculated.

Example:

```
Pulse: 100-> By user
average:-> calculation of Pulse/3 
Steps: 234-> By user
quantity:-> calculation of Average * Steps
```

Is this possible to make with QT such a form?

Answer (score 2):

I used QtDesigner to generate a `QDialog` like this:[image]

and disabled average and quantity `QLineEdits` (please note that I did not use any layout - you should use one to make it look nicer!). In QGis the *.ui file is set as form in attributes table and `form_open()` is used as python init function, see also documentation here: http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/de/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/forms.html#hard-fa-associating-the-form-with-your-layer

Code to calculate average and quantity when changing pulse or steps values looks like this:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QLineEdit, QSpinBox

form = None
steps = None
pulse = None


def form_open(my_dialog, layer_id, feature_id):
    global form
    global pulse
    global steps

    form = my_dialog
    pulse = form.findChild(QSpinBox, "pulse")
    pulse.valueChanged.connect(calculate_avg_and_quantity)
    steps = form.findChild(QSpinBox, "steps")
    steps.valueChanged.connect(calculate_avg_and_quantity)


def calculate_avg_and_quantity():
    average = form.findChild(QLineEdit, "average")
    quantity = form.findChild(QLineEdit, "quantity")

    new_average = pulse.value() / 3.0
    average.setText(str(round(new_average, 2)))

    new_quantity = new_average * steps.value()
    quantity.setText(str(new_quantity))
```